# Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Converting circular structure to JSON in .NET7

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

I have created a Blazor Server application in .NET6.but recently I've upgraded it to.NET7.since this time,i am getting above issue .

> Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'
> --- property 'window' closes the circle
> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'
> --- property 'window' closes the circle
> at JSON.stringify ()

this issue is occurring from this line

```
await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
```

this line is responsible for opening a URL in a new tab on the browser. once I click on a navigation bar link, the above line is called and occurred this issue.is there anybody who knows an answer to this issue? please help me, appreciate all your answers.

Answer (score 35):

I changed this line

```
await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
```

as this

```
await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "_blank");
```

after that, I didn't get that issue.

Comment: Good catch. I've also ran into the same problem and this fix worked like a charm.
Thank you!

Comment: Can somebody explain why this is the case?

Comment: More details about why this is happening can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16632